# Need Help regarding fixing TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/create Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value: bootstrap4/uni_form.html

Tags: django-templates

We are using PyCharm 2022.2 for django development and have the following setting in the settings.py file

[image]

[image]

and installed django-crispy-forms using the following command

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

and django-cripsy-forms library availabe under project libraries

[image]

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class AppUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_users'
        managed  = False
```

below is urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from accounts.views import UserCreateView

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/create', UserCreateView.as_view(), name='accounts-create')
]
```

below is our base.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Django Form Example with Bootstrap 4</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container d-flex h-100">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-10">
          <h1> Django Form Example with Bootstrap 4 </h1>
          {% block main %}
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the main page create_app_user.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block main %}
<form  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Error:

[image]
[image]

need help in fixing the issue..

Answer (score 1):

solved myself.. installing crispy-bootstrap4 package :-)

```
pip install crispy-bootstrap4
```

and 'crispy-boostrap4' under INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap4',           <--- This one fixed the problem
    'contact',
    'employee',
    'mycollections',
    'address',
]
```

the above settings fixed the problem